# Laravel 5.2 : Login "attempt" Event Handling

Tags: authentication, event-handling, laravel-5, custom-fields

In Laravel 5.2, i need to do something **while** the authentication process is being triggered. (Not "after" the login.)

Here are what i have done.

In `EventServiceProvider.php`:

```
protected $listen = [
  'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting' => ['App\Listeners\UserLoginAttempt@handle'],
];
```

In `app/Listeners/UserLoginAttempt.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;

class UserLoginAttempt
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function handle($event)
    {
        dd(Auth::user());
        exit;
    }
}
```

This always returns `null`.

** In fact, i have one "custom" field in the Login form, of which i need to capture from the above Event Handler. (I need to check something **before** actual Login event is done.)

- How do i capture the `Auth::user()` from this (Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting) Handler please?
- (In other words) How do i talk with the Login Form from the (Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting) Handler?
- OR ----- Is the `Auth::user()` object created ONLY AFTER the login is fully processed? Which means i can not get it while in "attempting" stage?

Because i need to **capture** the login elements first, and if it is something "unauthorized" *(after some calculations done in Handler)*, then i need to terminate the login attempt and route back to the login form from here.. by carrying the Failing Message along.

Please let me know what i'm missing here. Thank you.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) you are right that `Auth::user()` object created once user is authenticated.

Comment: @Abbasi Thanks for the helps. In this case, what do you think is the **proper** way to grab the Elements submitted from the Login Form please? (Using `$_GET["my_custom_field"]` like this ugly?)

Comment: Use `Request` e.g. `$my_custom_field = $request->input('my_custom_field');` if you provide your controller method where you are trying to achieve this would be quite easy to guide further.

Comment: Hi @Abbasi, thanks for all your helps with Laravel knowledge :D Could you please kindly help on this issue also (please?) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180161/laravel-5-2-how-to-call-sendfailedloginresponse-from-custom-login-event-hand (Big thanksss!) :D

Comment: Welcome, I'm adding an answer for it, might help someone else too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) you are right that `Auth::user()` object is only created when user is authenticated.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That means the `Auth::user()` is useless while in "attempting" stage.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting listener;
you can capture the form field by

```
public function handle(Attempting $event)
{
      //return dd($event); // will echo all fields
      $event->credentials['email']; // capturing the email field
}
```

you can also use the User model and then access the user table in DB, to get / check a user field in DB...