# Laravel 5.2 : How to call "sendFailedLoginResponse" from custom Login Event Handler?

Tags: authentication, event-handling, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.2, there is a function already **overriden** in my `AuthController.php`:

```
public function sendFailedLoginResponse()
{
    $errors = new MessageBag([
                'email' => ['Error message for email'],
                'password' => ['Error message for password'],
                'mycustominput' => ['Error message for my custom input field'],
        ]);

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($errors);
}
```

**This alone works (like magic) via normal FAILED login attempts.** *(When login is failed, the login form already shows this custom error messages, instead of the default ones. So this is getting triggered. So is ok.)*

---

Now i have below **Custom** Login Event Handler, registered in the `EventServiceProvider.php`:

```
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => ['App\Listeners\UserLoggedIn']
```

And then, i wanna TRIGGER the overridden function `sendFailedLoginResponse()` from this Custom Login Event Handler. Something like:

`app/Listeners/UserLoggedIn.php`:

```
// Some codes at top

public function handle(Login $event)
{
    // Some coding ..
    // Some custom verifications ..

    if ( $customLoginCheck == false ) 
    {
        ????::sendFailedLoginResponse(); // <----- Here call/trigger the method!
    }
}
```

When i tried using `Auth::sendFailedLoginResponse()`, it gives me following errors:

```
ErrorException in AuthManager.php line 288:
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard' does not have a method 'sendFailedLoginResponse'
```

Because i do NOT know "how" to call that desired function from a Custom Event Handler. (And also don't know what are the required includes.)

Please help to suggest. (Thanks all)

Comment: Can you show where are you triggering your Event..

Comment: Hi @Abbasi Since i have registered the custom Handler in `EventServiceProvider.php`, the `public function handle` (inside my custom `UserLoggedIn.php`) is already being triggered .. once i logged in. It is already being triggered. (I'm afraid i don't get your question.)

Comment: I mean where are you firing your event it should be something like `Event::fire(new Login());`?

Comment: Ermm... once you register your custom handler in `EventServiceProvider.php`, then in your Handler File , the `public function handle(){ ... }` is already triggered automatically. (At least for me, in LV `5.2`) That's all i did, and it is then already being triggered.

Comment: Yes, you are right but it will be fired anyhow. Please have a look at [this](https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-5-events), it might help you understand it.